# ImageMagick convert process causing deadly CPU load and killing available swap space in an instant

Tags: php, memory, imagemagick, cpu-usage

Today a customer's server went down after a user uploaded a 16MB JPG which then got processed by an automated, cron-controlled script which has been running flawlessly for months, successfully processing at least a thousand images.

After some investigation i figured that indeed that certain image is causing ImageMagick trouble. I downloaded the image to my local system (OSX Mavericks, ImageMagick 6.8.6-6 Q16) and ran the exact same `convert` command on it:

> convert test.jpg icc:profile.icc
>
> convert test.jpg -crop 3567x5340+125+0 +repage -resample 200x200 -resize 3937x5906 -compress lzw -profile ./profile.icc out.tif

Immediately everything stalls, the system gets slow and after a few seconds i get this message:

[image: Error message from OSX]

And in the terminal it says:

> convert: unable to extend cache `test.jpg': No space left on device @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3661.

My drive has a clear **73 GB of free space**, although i am certain that swap space is not exactly referring to that. Then again i have never before encountered such an issue.

So much for local testing.

On the server (CentOs 6.5 Final, ImageMagick 6.8.6 Q16) the main symptoms are a high CPU load causes by the `convert` process, causing some kind of stapling of further `convert` processes which may get called through users navigating the website in yet uncached areas, triggering `convert` executions for the purpose thumbnail generation. But these never exceed even a percent of CPU usage. The `convert` process that should work through the image in question however, that one i have seen to go up to almost a 100%.

**Sideinfos**

I use a normal call to `exec()` to run `convert`. Forking as a separate process doesn't seem like much of an option (not even sure if PCNTL is available), nor would it help much, other than that the `convert` process would then just continue running in circles until infinity==null (so to speak).

PHP's memory limit is set to 128 M on the server (on my test machine i called the process manually from the terminal).

PHP's max_execution_time is set to 300, for we need a certain amount of buffer to assure proper processing of a whole stack of images. Note that this system has worked stable and properly managed to process entire packs of images, not seldom exceeding a count of 25 pieces a time (all of which were larger than the image in question).

**Note**

Even though i would like to, due to copyright issues i cannot provide the original image. But perhaps someone has ran into the same or a similar issue and can therefore give valuable input that may server in solving the problem or at least finding out what exactly causes it.

Comment: remove `-resample` you are converting a huge an even larger image!

Comment: Thank you, that's valuable input! But how can i assure the desired DPI without resampling the image?

Comment: resample after your resize?

Comment: Oh goodness. That makes an awful lot of sense. Give me a minute to test this.

Comment: Alright - so the problem does **not** occur when i completely refrain from resampling. But unfortunately, when changing the command order so that resampling is done after resizing, the problem persists.

Comment: doh!  can you run the resample as a second command ie output the tif, then run just the resample on it

Comment: Tried it right now. Same result. Completely kills all resources. Impressive actually, its a normal JPG with 8 Bit depth, 72 DPI, 5.340x3.817px ..

Comment: I am still dealing with this issue. I am not sure how to go about resampling my image properly. I have a target format (W x H) and a target DPI i need to achieve.

Comment: have you tried the `-density` command? what is the images dpi?

Comment: Yes, i think i figured it out now. The original image has 1440 DPI, the target DPI is 200. The results look ok now. OSX Preview / File info gives me the correct 200 DPI for both axis, but the problem is that photoshop is still saying the image has 1440 DPI. The command looks like this now: `convert file.jpg -crop 3963x2642+0+0 +repage -units PixelsPerInch -resize 4724x3150 -extent 4724x3150 -density 200 -compress lzw out.tif`

Comment: What if you do this `convert -density 1440 test.jpg -crop 3567x5340+125+0 +repage -resample 200x200 -resize 3937x5906 -compress lzw -profile ./profile.icc out.tif` the density command goes before the image

Comment: Just tried it. It unfortunately results in a blurry image.

Comment: @cmorrissey Your initial suggestion was correct - it was an issue caused by the resampling. Please provide an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: As for density: it was useful but didn't do the trick. The problem was that Photoshop (and many professional print systems) rely on the originally embedded DPI count. No matter how i handled `-units`, `-density` or `-resample`, i never got the correct results when opening the final image in Photoshop. The DPI was always wrong, despite other tools saying something else. The only solution was to composite the original over a white canvas, whereas the old DPI information got lost and there was only the `-density` setting to rely on.